# Help on how I should solve combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics

• Find the probability that if we sample with replacement (ı.e. repetitions are allowed) 6 letters of a 26-letter alphabet, we find a string with 3 different letters each repeated twice (e.g. ”aabbcc”, ”acabcb”, ”xyxyzz”, ”zxyyzx”, etc.)
[image]

I can understand the final outcome of this probability but I cannot think of the methodology although I have solved a lot of questions related to combinations, permutations, shuffling,partitions with the multiplication rules and many counting techniques (star and bars, allocation and sampling with and without replacement and with or without order..) However, whenever I face a new question the methodology changes the logic changes too and  I have to take into consideration some new details and restrictions.I am still not able to have a big clear image of those techniques in my head and whenever I face a combinatorics problem I am stuck. can you guide me on hon I should think? 
Maybe it can be less complicated than imagined.
ps : I practiced too much and posted many questions on math exchange(but still depending on the solution or a help every time does not solve the problem).

[image]

This is so far the table that I know about combinatorics and I can understand the conceptual part of each formula but cannot apply it to the problem I know.
I’ll give you below some idea about the kind and level of problems that we tackle in combinatorics.
enter image description here

[image][image]

Comment: Are you looking for general advice, or are you looking for advice for this *specific* question?  In any problem, there are different ways of looking at it.  The way I look at this problem I think about how many length-6 strings exist without restriction and compare this to the number of length-6 strings that exist with the desired restrictions.  To count that, lets first pick what the letters that appear are, and then once that is selected pick in what order they appear.

Comment: In fact I am more looking for general advice

Comment: This can be solved by counting.  The probability assumes all six letter strings are equally likely,  so divide the number of all *specified* strings by the count of all six letter strings.  The key is to count in a way that doesn't miss any strings and doesn't overcount any string more than once.

Comment: As for general advice, just look at and practice several examples.  Perhaps more importantly, look at other people's *incorrect* attempts so you can see what mistakes they made so that you can avoid making the same mistakes in the future.  Similarly, make attempts yourself too, even if they are incorrect.  Making mistakes is sometimes the best way to learn.

Comment: As for additional general advice, once you have built a sufficiently large toolkit with various methods and counting formulas (e.g. inclusion-exclusion, binomial coefficients, etc...), when you encounter a new problem see if you can reword it in such a way that it is in fact just an older problem you've already encountered in disguise (*or sequence of older problems combined*).  [Stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) for example is really just a fancy application of binomial coefficients that required the right way of thinking about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Solving these kinds of problems comes with practicing a lot of them.

When I answer these, I tend to use the word "pick" a lot.

For the question you posed, I'd pick the three repeated letters $_{26}C_3$. For the first letter alphabetically, I'd pick the two slots of the six where they go $_6C_2$. Then I'd pick the two of the four remaining slots where the next letter alphabetically goes $_4C_2$. (The last two letters I have no choice.)

That counts the strings that satisfy what I'm looking for (three different but repeated letters).

For *any* string, I'd pick the first letter $(26)$, the second letter, $(26)$, and so forth, for a total of $26^6$ possible strings.

Dividing the number of strings I'm looking for by the total number of possible strings gives the answer (B).